# Ruby/Kimurai/Capybara/Selenium/Chrome: clicking only works when the window is visible. Is this expected behaviour?

Tags: ruby, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, capybara

This code works perfectly well when I have headless=false and the browser window is actually on the screen:

```
require 'kimurai'
require "capybara"
require "capybara/sessionkeeper"

Capybara.register_driver :chrome do |app|
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, browser: :chrome)
end

class SimpleSpider < Kimurai::Base
  @name = "simple_spider"
  @engine = :selenium_chrome
  @start_urls = ["some_url"]
  @config = {
    cookies: YAML.load_file('./config/cookies.yml')
  }

  def parse(response, url:, data: {})
    yaml_str = browser.cookies_to_yaml
    File.write('./config/cookies.yml', yaml_str)
    browser.all(:xpath, '//div[contains(text(), "17")]')[0].click 
  end
end

SimpleSpider.crawl!
```

If I run it in headless mode or I simply minimize the window, I get an error:

```
undefined method `click' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
```

Is this normal? does the screen has to be on the display for this to work? If not, how to fix it?

Thanks

Comment: You should not be minimizing the window, but it should work in Chromes headless mode, assuming the page is not detecting headless mode and showing different content - how are you enabling headless? What version of Capybara are you using?

Comment: headless is enabled by default with kimurai according to their github: https://github.com/vifreefly/kimuraframework#available-engines

:selenium_chrome Chrome in headless mode driven by selenium. Modern headless browser solution with proper javascript rendering.


I'm using capybara 3.14

Comment: Have you tried outputting `browser.html` to see what the page actually is, and verify the page isn't detecting headless mode and displaying alternate content. -- Also if you just want the first matching element, you're going to be better off using `first` rather than `all` and indexing.

Comment: You're right! It is displaying alternate content! I output the HTML and the whole website was replaced by a big message "Oops! This window is too narrow for your calendar." Widening it!

Comment: I don't personally run headless mode, but I know that running headless for chrome can be wonky if you do not explicitly set the window size (even though there is no visible window). I've never touched Ruby, so I don't know the syntax here, but find the Ruby Selenium API to set the window size to what would be a normal size that renders content as you would expect. This may fix that issue you mention about, and will help with the driver clicking the x,y coordinates it intends to click.